# remove/disable top-links-container form header

Tags: magento-1.9

How do i completely remove/disable top-links-container from the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in your theme `local.xml` file

located `app/design/fronend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/local.xml`

```
<default>
  <reference name="header">    
    <remove name="top.links">
  </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: thanks. it's gone but messes up the website. Tried to put in all the code you gave me or only the <remove name="top.links"> and added that in the header section of the local.xml

Comment: @bramvds at the end of the file put this code

Comment: really i did. but i the website looks like this after that: https://postimg.org/image/m054lz3sn/

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your local.xml :

```
    <default>
            <reference name="header">
                <remove name="top.links"/>
            </reference>
    </default>
```

if you want to remove the particular link:

1. Customer links:  app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\customer.xml

comment below code :

```
<!--<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
  <label>My Account</label>
  <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
  <title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/>
  <position>10</position>
</action>-->
```

2. Wishlist Link: app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\wishlist.xml

Comment code :

```
<!--<reference name="top.links">
 <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
 <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
</reference>-->
```

3. Cart & Checkout Link :      app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\

Comment code :

```
<!--<reference name="top.links"> 
 <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link"> 
  <action method="addCartLink"></action> 
  <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action> 
 </block> 
</reference> –->
```